# WP ALL Import plugin - import data from certain ids

Tags: plugins, import

I want to import xml file including items with p tags with ids. But the order od p tags in different items are different, so the imported values are not corresponding values from ids. For example element with id 70 is on the 10-th place, but in other item the p with id 70 is on the 12-th position. How can I import this data correctly?

[image]